# Studies showing time taken on stages (coding, test, maintenance) of software product development?

Tags: testing

Are there any studies showing time spent on various stages of a product life cycle, especially test?  Actual numbers and references would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

The time spent on stages of software development are extremely dependent on the methodology used.

I think that a good place to start your research is searching for 'software development case study' in [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/). That way you will be able to find references and the numbers that you want.

Comment: This can't be overstated. Every paper I've read assumes the use of one methodology or another in development. Intuitively, it makes sense that when you change design paradigms that it changes the time spent in each phase, but more than that, it's what you DECIDE to put into each phase.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at this paper:

An Experimental Investigation of Software Metrics and Their Relationship to Software Development Effort

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=65481

There are a lot of references in this paper that you can follow up on for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Case Study
● TDD project has twice the code quality
● Writing tests requires 15% more time
IBM Case Study
● 40% fewer defects
● No impact on the team's productivity
John Deere / Ericsson Case Study
● TDD produces higher quality code
● Impact of 16% on the team's productivity
http://derickrethans.nl/files/tdd-phpworks8.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Testing is an interesting animal. As mentioned, the chosen methodology will dictate how much time should be spent testing, but in the end, it's up to the engineers to allocate test time, number of tests, number of tests for each module, etc. appropriately.